# SQL - Counting a column twice

Tags: sql, count

I have a table that has a column called 'status'. This can be set to 0 or 1

Is it possible for me to count both the 0's and 1's in a single query?

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Both current answers are good - Yuck's if you need pure counts, ean5533's if you need to add further columns/more grouping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just group on the value of `status`:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY status
```

That will give you exactly two rows since the value can only be `0` or `1`, and the `COUNT(*)` column will be the number of times each `status` value appears in the table.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of zeroes',
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of ones'
FROM yourtable;
```