# Counting same column multiple times, already grouped

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I'm trying to count all the "Y"s and "N"s in one column but group them by another column. I can get it to pull just the "Y" or the "N" with a WHERE:

```
SELECT TABLE2.GROUP_BY_THIS,COUNT(TABLE1.FLAG)
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN
TABLE2 On TABLE1.Primary_Key = TABLE2.Foreign_Key
WHERE TABLE1.FLAG_Required = "Y"
GROUP BY TABLE2.GROUP_BY_THIS
```

and I can see the "Y"s and "N"s for the whole data set and not grouped by the other column using the first answer here: [SQL - Counting a column twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316765/sql-counting-a-column-twice/9316788#9316788) but I'm not too sure how to get my desired outcome which should look a little like this:

```
GROUP_BY_THIS  Y COUNT  N COUNT
-------------------------------
GROUP1         10       1
GROUP2         10       100
GROUP3         0        10
GROUP4         50       500
GROUP5         1000     0
```

Do I need a further grouping somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  TABLE2.GROUP_BY_THIS
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN TABLE1.FLAG = 'Y' THEN 1 END)
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN TABLE1.FLAG = 'N' THEN 1 END)
FROM    TABLE1 
JOIN    TABLE2 
ON      TABLE1.Primary_Key = TABLE2.Foreign_Key
GROUP BY 
        TABLE2.GROUP_BY_THIS
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be SUM() instead of COUNT()?

Comment: @frikozoid in this case when no `ELSE` was specified and the value for true condition is 1, `COUNT()` and `SUM()` will produce the same result.

Comment: @Andomar Oh, OK. NULLs don't count :). +1